# draggable chart editing - edit values of chart by drag

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm using amcharts and make a live edit chart like this example (jsfiddle) :

```
jsfiddle.net/amcharts/9uyAf/
```

My own chart (below image) : (now I can change values by changing input values)
[image]

**I try** to find a alternate way to edit values of chart by **dragging the values of chart instead of changing values on inputs** .

**Is there** a example or chart library have this features ?

tnx ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZingChart offers a way to drag the values OR change the values on inputs.  They call it Node Dragging.

There is a demo of this feature at http://www.zingchart.com/playground/presentation/51b21654ca9e7

You can right click the chart to view source for this demo, as well.

Comment: Hi, the demo link is no longer available